# Pipenv: What types of github reference can you use for the "ref" argument?

Tags: python, github, repository, pipenv

When using pipenv to pull in a github repo, what types of references can be used for the "ref" argument?

Can it be a feature branch?
Can it be a release version?
Can it be a tagged branch?

I've reviewed the documentation here:

https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/basics/#a-note-about-vcs-dependencies

```
# Pipfile with tag version (v0.0.2):
my-sdk = {editable = true,git = "git@github.com/MyDev/my-sdk.git", ref = "v0.1.2"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the `pip` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git), you can use a "branch name, a commit hash, a tag name or a git ref". So any branch, tag, full ref, or commit hash is allowed.

It may additionally be possible to use an arbitrary Git revision expression, but that isn't documented to work.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about it being documented in pip.